# Does embedded RavenDB work in a load balanced environment?

Tags: deployment, transactions, distributed, load-balancing, ravendb

I'm writing a webapp which uses an embedded instance of RavenDB as its database. I would like to deploy this webapp to a particular hosting provider. This hosting provider provides load balanced web servers that share the same filesystem. I.e, each web server's embedded RavenDB instance would be able to access the RavenDB data files. But would this setup work with, for example, transactions? Would it work at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RavenDB won't work if you point 2 embedded instances at the save data folder (on disk). You'll get errors because it expects only one instance to be accessing the files at any one time.

You could however have 2 separate instances, each with their own folder on disk and then replicate between the 2 of them.